# Get documents between two dates

Tags: arangodb, aql

In my collection I have some documents and one of their values is the `created_on` key, that is filled by timestamp at the creation of the document.

I want to retrieve the documents created between two dates, but I can't get it in a simple way, i have the next:

```
FOR d IN mycollection
FILTER '2021-12-01' <= DATE_FORMAT(d.created_on, "%yyyy-%mm-%dd") <= '2021-12-05'
SORT d.created_on ASC 
RETURN DATE_FORMAT(d.created_on, "%yyyy-%mm-%dd")
```

but the above query returns all the records, not only the documents that are in the specified time period.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do your timestamps look like? Are they unix epochs, ISO encoded timestamps, ...?

Comment: If at all possible, try to store your timestamps in unix epoch format, as they are stored as integers and it is easy to do the query you are looking to do. If you have the ability to store a second date column in that format, you will find your solution.

Comment: @mpoeter this is the timestamp aspect 1634071540171

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your filter expression `'2021-12-01' <= DATE_FORMAT(d.created_on, "%yyyy-%mm-%dd") <= '2021-12-05'`
This is basically the same as

```
LET x = '2021-12-01' <= DATE_FORMAT(d.created_on, "%yyyy-%mm-%dd")
FILTER x <= '2021-12-05'
```

`x` is a bool and as such always compares less than a string.

You should rewrite your query as follows:

```
FOR d IN mycollection
  LET date = DATE_FORMAT(d.created_on, "%yyyy-%mm-%dd")
  FILTER '2021-12-01' <= date AND date <= '2021-12-05'
  SORT d.created_on ASC 
  RETURN DATE_FORMAT(d.created_on, "%yyyy-%mm-%dd")
```

This should filter correctly, but you won't be able to utilize any indexes on `created_an` for the FILTER, only for the SORT. So instead it would be better to write the query as follows:

```
LET from = DATE_TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01')
LET to = DATE_TIMESTAMP('2021-12-05')
FOR d IN mycollection
  FILTER from <= d.created_on AND d.created_on <= to
  SORT d.created_on ASC 
  RETURN DATE_FORMAT(d.created_on, "%yyyy-%mm-%dd")
```

Comment: thanks, i tried to apply the chain comparison like on python, but I see that i need to make two comparisons in a separated way